# Is the PureRenderMixin mixin obsolete now?

Tags: reactjs

If one is using [stateless functions](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#stateless-functions) in React for dumb render-only components, is PureRenderMixin even needed anymore? If it still does serve some purpose in modern container/stateless React structures, what is it?

Comment: +1 I just added this question to my todo list to be explored sometime. Hope we'll get an answer and save some time.

Answer (score 1):

`PureRenderMixin` is helpful for both stateless and stateful components, since it gives you the option to cancel an update if either change.

Stateless Functional components are **not** pure by default, they are just "stateless", which isn't the same thing. Pure components are components whose render output is the same given a the same set of inputs, (props and state). Just like functions don't have to be pure (i.e they can have side effects) so too can functional components.

They may be relying on closure state:

```
let state = { bar: true }

let Foo = (props) => <span {...props} {...state} />
```

Or more likely a prop may not be immutable:

```
let List = props => (
  <ul>{props.list.map(item => <li>{item}</li>)</ul>
)
```

Where `list` can have items added or removed without changing the reference to the array

In any case just because a component is stateless and functional is not the same as it being pure by default.

To answer the main question: no they aren't obsolete, because the mutable nature of JavaScript data means that you can't just assume props are immutable, and so the pure render optimization can't just be turned on by default for components, functional or not

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! So, `PureRenderMixin` implements a `shouldComponentUpdate` that returns `false` if the props and state are equal to their previous values. I'm having trouble thinking of a scenario where a stateless component would update even though the props remained the same.

Comment: well generally it wouldn't, but you could have props stay the "same" but be different, ie. it needs an update because the array has a new item, even tho `lastProps.array === this.props.array` is true. Often stateless components are more easily "pure" but you can't just assume it, hence functional components aren't optimized that way by default. Since data in JS is not reliably immutable this sort of optimization must always be "opt-in"